# Why the numeric promotion of integer and double operands not happen?

Tags: java

In my recent work, I met a question, which is about the numeric promotion of some operands. The following is the demo code:

```
int num1 = 9999999;
int num2 = 65536;
double result = num1*num2*1.0;
```

In my opinion, I thought both of num1 and num2 will be automatically promotion to double and then calculate the result as one of the operands is a double, while the result shocked me. I got a negative number.
And then I look into the JLS, it also says it should do the numeric promotion, see below:

"If at least one of the operands to a binary operator is of floating-point type, then the operation is a floating-point operation, even if the other is integral.

If at least one of the operands to a numerical operator is of type double, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit floating-point arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of type double. If the other operand is not a double, it is first widened (§5.1.5) to type double by numeric promotion (§5.6).

Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit floating-point arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of type float. (If the other operand is not a float, it is first widened to type float by numeric promotion.)"

And if I change the result to 1.0*num1*num2, it will give me the right answer. Could anybody tell me what the hell is this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the result of `num1 * num2` is promoted to double. Your statement is equivalent to:

```
double result = (num1 * num2) * 1.0;
```

So with promotion, that would be:

```
int firstMultiplication = num1 * num2;
double promoted = firstMultiplication;
double result = promoted * 1.0;
```

Basically, this is *just* a matter of operator precedence. Numeric promotion happens to operands - not every expression which was involved in evaluating that operand to start with.

Comment: The very first rule to apply is the evaluation order of the operators of an expression. For two *'s it is left to right.

Comment: @BackSlash: Well personally I'd just cast, as a simpler way of expressing my intention :)

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with operator precedence,

In your case what is happening is num1 and num2 are integers and they are calculated first and their result is also an integer, since the result is out of range its getting wrapped around thus  you are getting the result in negative, the next step is multiplication with 1.0. Here as you expect the result is promoted to double. But now we are aware that its too late.

You can try any of these

```
result=num1*1.0*num2;
result=1.0*num2*num1;
result=1.0*num1*num2;
```